# cx_oracle 6 for Oracle 12C version error

Tags: django, oracle, python-3.x, oracle12c, cx-oracle

I am trying to use oracle 12c as database for my application using Django framework. But I am struck in version related issue

Following are the version of library used:

- Python 3.6
- cx_Oracle 6
- Oracle instant client 12.2
- Oracle 12 C database on server
- Oracle 10 g on local machine where the cx_oracle
  is installed

OS is windows 7

Following are the steps which I did to install cx_oracle

1. pip install cx_Oracle
2. Download Oracle instant client 12.2 zip file for windows
3. Extracted the zip file
4. Added the above unzipped folder to user PATH variable

From CMD I try to execute

```
python 
import cx_Oracle 
con = cx_Oracle.connect(uname, pwd, server_ip:port/name)
```

I am getting the error:

**cx_oracle.databaseerror: dpi-1050: oracle client library must be at version 11.2 or higher**

Is cx_Oracle having any conflict with oracle 10 g installed at local machine
I cannot upgrade the local oracle 10g db because(no rights given)

How do I resolved the above issue. 
How can I make sure cx_Oracle uses the correct Oracle instant client( i.e, 12.2) to connect to server db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use set ORACLE_HOME too:

```
SET ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle\client_12_1
SET PATH=C:\Oracle\client_12_1\bin;%PATH%
python 
import cx_Oracle 
con = cx_Oracle.connect(uname, pwd, server_ip:port/name)
```

Comment: Do not set ORACLE_HOME when using instant client!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the directory containing the instant client is earlier in the PATH environment variable than your 10g installation. That should resolve it for you.